# Regular expression not worknig

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression in javascript with the following rules:

> 1. At least 2 characters.
> 2. Should have at least 1 letter as a prefix and end with a `.` or have  or `-` and then have more letters.

The following strings should be legal - `aa`, `aaaaa`, `a.`, `a-a`, `a a`.
These should not be legal - `a` (too short), `aa.aa.` (two dots), `aa-` (after `-` should be another letter).

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here but my regex doesn't seem to work, as it is legal yet no word matches it:

```
(?=^.{2,}$)^(([a-z][A-Z])+([.]|[ -][a-zA-Z]+){0,1}$)
```

Comment: please edit your question and format your code using the editor tools. Also, add which language you're trying to do the regex in.

Comment: Perhaps editing the question and adding some valid/invalid examples would help.

Comment: @SebastianProske please don't recommend bad formatting, the editor has all the tools necessary to format code properly. Backticks are for inline code blocks and 4 space indentation is used for multiline code blocks.

Comment: @Rotem B as you have updated your question, I have updted my answer too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to re-write it completely to cover op's comment. The new regex would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[ -][a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]$|^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]|\.)$
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/wKcbve/1)

1st Alternative `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[ -][a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]$`

> 1. ^ asserts position at start of a line
> 2. [a-zA-Z] Match a single character present in [a-zA-Z]
> 3. [a-zA-Z]* * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited
>      times(greedy)
> 4. [ -] Match a single character - or a space
> 5. $ asserts position at the end of a line

2nd Alternative
 `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]|\.)$`

> 1. ^ asserts position at start of a line
> 2. [a-zA-Z] Match a single character present in [a-zA-Z]
> 3. [a-zA-Z]* * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited
>      times(greedy)
> 4. ([a-zA-Z]|.) Match a single character present in the list below
>      [a-zA-Z] or dot
> 5. $ asserts position at the end of a line

Comment: It would be good if you used the live code snippets that SO supports to demonstrate this actually doing the match.

Comment: @Soviut I actually don't know much about live code snippet, haven't studied on it yet. regex101 link has been shared though.

Comment: I saw a blank space in the regex, also, `-` in `[a-zA-Z -]` does not mean `character -`. Do you need `\-`?

Comment: As you said, I have converted - to \-

Comment: @TânNguyễn `-` can be left unescaped if at the end of a character class. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @SebastianProske true that

Comment: I have a few problems here - first, "a-a-a" is legal and I want to allow 1 "-" or " " at most. Second, "a-a." Should be not be legal as I want to allow up to 1 special character.

Comment: You should remove the pipe from the character class because it is not wanted.

Comment: updated, you are right... i had different plan, then when i changed back to character class i forgot to remove it... good point

Comment: Thanks for the great and nicely explained answer